Material React - Unpinning of Columns Event Listener
Any one knows the event emitter for unpinning of columns for material react table?
onColumnPinningChange={(newPinning) => { props?.onColumnPinningChange(newPinning); }}

this one only works if you are pinning but can't get the event if you unpinned
what was your workaround if there will be no unpin event emitter

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
